# Why this code gives different output for differents runs

Tags: plotting, conditional

**Edit**

Here is my code to plot many constrained variables in (x,y) plan :

the variables are :

```
   k1[x_,y_]:= 1/(2v^2 Cos[x]^2)(Sin[y]^2 m2^2+Cos[y]^2 m1^2)

    k2[x_,y_]:= 1/(2v^2 Sin[x]^2)(Cos[y]^2 m2^2+Sin[y]^2 m1^2)
```

with`v = 178 Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMssy.png); m1 = 125; m2 = 750;

Now to make a plot satisfies conditions on `k1 and k2` in ArcTan(x) and
ArcTan(y) plan I used the following code:

```
ClearAll[ps]

ps = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0.1, 2.}, 1000], RandomReal[{-1, 3}, 1000]}];

styleps3 = 
  Style[{##}, PointSize[.01], 
     Piecewise[{{Blue, 
        0 < k1[ArcTan[#], ArcTan[#2]] <= 4 Pi && 
         0 < Sin[ArcTan[#] - ArcTan[#2]] <= 0.01 && 
         0 < k2[ArcTan[#], ArcTan[#2]] <= 4 Pi}}, White]] & @@@ ps;

 ListPlot[styleps3, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray]]
```

Now the problem is that as `RandomReal` is used in this code, only some points are generated which satisfy the required conditions, while there may be still other points satisfy the conditions and has not been generated .. this can be clear when the `ListPlot` graph gives different points at each run (as plots below)

So any suggestions to improve this code or make alternative to can plot whole points of of tan y versus tan x satisfy required conditions for any run ?

[image]

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but aren't you evaluating `RandomReal` each time?

Comment: Yap, I make ClearAll[ps], and retry or quit the kernal at all then begin again ..

Comment: So why are you expecting it to be the same?

Comment: Oh, that's right .. but how I get the exact points of tan(y)  versus tan tan(x) which meet all conditions .. I mean now I can't specify , for one run it gives two points, while for other it gives 5 points ?

Comment: Can you give detailed example @Kuba ?

Comment: Can I just avoid to use `RandomReal` at all in this code .. because like that I can't determine `exactly the required points`, which is serious problem for me ..

Comment: So what do you want  to determine? Please replace all those complicated formulas with simple condition and tell use what you expect to get from it.

Comment: Hay @kuba I edit my question .. I hope it's simpler now

Comment: No sorry, simple example is e.g. something like `condition[x_] := .1 < x < .5; ` maybe modified to reflect critical features of the problem. Maybe it will be good enough for someone and you will receive help but I don't have time to think about those `ArcTans`, sorry.

Comment: It's ok .. I don't know why I thought when I write my own code it will be better .. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach similar to the one [I proposed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119095/27951) in [your more recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119081/27951).

Due to the way you had constructed your conditions, this time I found it more expedient to use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) instead of `Select`. `Pick` required the generation of an intermediate `selector` list, but this step doesn't really slow down computations too much; in the end, the time-to-plot seems dominated by `ListPlot` when the number of points is large enough.

```
Clear[k1, k2]
v = 178 Sqrt@2; m1 = 125; m2 = 750;
k1[x_, y_] := 1/(2 v^2 Cos[x]^2) (Sin[y]^2 m2^2 + Cos[y]^2 m1^2)
k2[x_, y_] := 1/(2 v^2 Sin[x]^2) (Cos[y]^2 m2^2 + Sin[y]^2 m1^2)

ps = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0.1, 2}, {-1, 3}}], 1*^6];

selector = 
  0 < k1[ArcTan[#1], ArcTan[#2]] <= 4 Pi && 
     0 < Sin[ArcTan[#1] - ArcTan[#2]] <= 0.01 && 
     0 < k2[ArcTan[#1], ArcTan[#2]] <= 4 Pi & @@@ ps;

ptsToPlot = Pick[ps, selector];

ListPlot[
  ptsToPlot,
  DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray], ImageSize -> 500
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Although this approach can be made to work, at least to some extent, ultimately a better result would be obtained with less effort using `RegionPlot` and `ImplicitRegion`, as Kuba has suggested in [his answer to your second question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119085/27951).

Comment: @ MarcoB . You are great .. deeply thanks :)

Comment: @ MarcoB . Can this code little bit modified to include loop on a third parameter , i.e. if we have  `k1[x_, y_,z_]` instead and z takes values say from 2 to 10, with all the same conditions on k1 and k2 ?

Comment: @S.S. How would this third parameter be involved in the conditions?

Comment: @ MarcoB. Hi , just add to k1, as  `selector = 0 < k1[ArcTan[#1], ArcTan[#2],z] <= 4 Pi && 0 < Sin[ArcTan[#1] - ArcTan[#2]] <= 0.01 && 0 < k2[ArcTan[#1], ArcTan[#2]] <= 4 Pi & @@@ ps;`

Comment: "Update" . Hi @ MarcoB , may be you find that for this case `ListPlot` won't depend at all on `z` variable, cause we plot so rare region with strong boundry `0 < Sin[ArcTan[#1] - ArcTan[#2]] <= 0.01` .. but you may look on my second post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119139/how-to-loop-over-a-varible-while-plotting-a-function… . you will find that `ListPlot` changes for different values of m, so Looping over `m` values can make a sense