# Selecting and plotting points belonging to a region from a random sample

Tags: plotting, random, regions

I'm facing a problem with `RandomReal` when using `ListPlot` to plot some constrained points. I found that at every run of MA kernel the graph's points changes. In details, suppose for instance, functions:

```
k1[s_, d_] := 3 s + 5 d

k2[s_, d_] := 5 s - 7 d
```

I'm using the following to plot conditional `k1` and `k2` in (s,d) plan

```
ClearAll[ps]

ps = Transpose[{RandomReal[{0.1, 2.}, 1000], RandomReal[{-1, 3}, 1000]}];

styleps = 
  Style[{##}, PointSize[.01], 
     Piecewise[{{Blue, 0 < k1[#, #2] <= 1 && 0 < k2[#, #2] <= 2}}, 
      White]] & @@@ ps;

ListPlot[styleps, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray]]
```

Now for the first run this gives:

[image]

While if I make `ClearAll[ps]` and rerun or quit the kernel and started again, this gives totally different points, such as:

[image]

This is expected from `RandomReal` because it generates random points each time, but this is totally confusing in this case , because how one can determine all real points which satisfy the required condition if in each run only some points are appear ?

So any suggestions to improve this code  to can plot whole points of of `s` versus `d` for which `k1` and `k2` conditions are satisfied  for any run?

Comment: Add a [`SeedRandom`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) call with an appropriate seed to get identical output from `RandomReal` every time you run it.

Comment: The problem is that even I fixed RandomReal for each run, it won't generate whole required points  for this fix but it will be upon my choice such as setting length of genertaed points, etc. Can I avoid `RandomReal` from the beginning and generate points in more efficient way  ?

Comment: @MarcoB have you an idea how to use `SeedRandom` in my example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that generates many more points than you had, selects the ones for which your conditions are met, and plots them:

```
k1[s_, d_] := 3 s + 5 d
k2[s_, d_] := 5 s - 7 d
ps = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0.1, 2}, {-1, 3}}], 1000000];

valid = Select[ps, 0 < k1[Sequence @@ #] <= 1 && 0 < k2[Sequence @@ #] <= 2 &];

ListPlot[
 valid,
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]},
 Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's interesting @MarcoB .. thanx

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is a dead end, you can't determine **all** points by picking them and checking conditions. Because there are infinitely many of them.

```
ImplicitRegion[
  0 < k1[x, y] <= 1 && 0 < k2[x, y] <= 2, 
  {x, y}
] // RegionPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kuba, it's pleasant to know my point is not reachable ..

Comment: @ Kuba I still have a question, how can we imply set length as you mentioned `condition[x_] := .1 < x < .5;
Module[{i = 0}, 
 First@Last@
   Reap@While[i < 5, If[condition[#], i++; Sow[#]] &@RandomReal[]]]` to my example ?  Also do you think `SeedRandom` mentioned above can do the same act with `RandomReal` ? sorry I wish if I'm an expert in MA ..`

Comment: @S.S. I don't understand, the cardinality of set of points fulfilling your conditions is the cardinality of the continuum. The problem isn't about MMA skills I think. p.s. `SeedRandom` and `RandomReal` are related but they do different things, press F1 and read more.

Comment: @ Kuba . I mean I try to use that Module in plotting for my example, if you have an idea..

Comment: @S.S. replace `i` with number of points you want to enerate, `RandomReal[1, {2}]` or something. I really don't know what is the goal, you can't get that way all the points.