# How to loop over a varible while plotting a function

Tags: plotting

Suppose three functions :

```
k1[s_, d_,m_] := 3 s + 5 d + m
k2[s_, d_] := 5 s - 7 d
k3[s_, d_,m_] :=  s + d - m
```

How to add the following code to plot conditional `ki` in (s,d) plan while looping over m values for a range, say form -3 to 2 ?

```
ps = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-2, 2.}, 1000],RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 1000]}];

styleps = Style[{##}, PointSize[.01], Piecewise[{{Blue, 0 < k1[#, #2, -3] <= 
10 && -2 < k2[#, #2] <= 2 && 0 < k3[#, #2, -3] <= 10}}, White]] & @@@ ps;

ListPlot[styleps, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]}, 
ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray]]
```

I think one can use `For` Loop, but I don't know exactly where it can be implied, any ideas?

Comment: So, you want one plot for each value of `m`..?

Comment: Yes I want while `ListPlot` don't fix `m` at single value .. otherwise give it a rang say from 2 to 10.

Comment: Make `styleps` a function of `m`, and put a `plots = Table[..., {m, 2, 10}];` around `ListPlot`...?

Comment: May be the first step is a good idea, i.e. `styleps[m_]`, but I think the second is not ..

Comment: Why? What do you want that a list of plots does not achieve? This is why I asked you if you want one plot for each value of m or `not`.

Comment: Just I'd like to use a loop as `For` .. I don't know each time I use `Table` I got improper points for my graphs, it may depends on the functions I'm dealing with , also I think making a loop will be more effective  .. in all cases thanks for help :)

Comment: A `For` loop will be one of the **least** efficient ways to do it. If you directly want to loop you can use `Do[..., {m,2,10}]` and then `Print[ListPlot[...]]` inside the body of `Do`, but why not just keep them in a `Table`? Then you can store them, put them in a `GraphicsGrid` etc. etc.

Comment: @  Marius Ladegård Meyer  can you give a detailed example on my code for `Do[..., {m,2,10}]` and  `Print[ListPlot[...]]` ? I think i'm not so brave in that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
k1[s_, d_, m_] := 3 s + 5 d + m
k2[s_, d_] := 5 s - 7 d
k3[s_, d_, m_] := s + d - m

ps = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-2, 2.}, 1000], 
    RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 1000]}];

styleps[m_] := 
  Style[{##}, PointSize[.01], 
     Piecewise[{{Blue, 
        0 < k1[#, #2, m] <= 10 && -2 < k2[#, #2] <= 2 && 
         0 < k3[#, #2, m] <= 10}}, White]] & @@@ ps;

plots = Table[
   ListPlot[styleps[m], DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], 
      Table[i, {i, -1, 3, 0.2}]}, ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> False, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray]], {m, 0, 2, 2/(10 - 1)}];
```

This gives 10 plots with `m` varying from 0 to 2. We can visualize it with an animation for instance:

```
Animate[plots[[u]], {u, 1, Length[tab], 1}]
```

Should show you something like this:

[image]

Comment: Really thanks guys, you are the best ones :)

Answer (score 6):

I personally would favour a `RegionPlot`

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot[{0 < k1[s, d, m] <= 1, 0 < k2[s, d] <= 2, 
 2 < k3[s, d, m] <= 5}, {s, -1, 1}, {d, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> m], {m, -5, -1}]
```

[image]

If you want to use `ListPlot`

```
col = {Red, Blue, Green};
mm = {-3.5, -2.5, -1.5};
Do[data[m] = {}; 
Do[If[0 < k1[s, d, m] <= 1 && 0 < k2[s, d] <= 2 && 2 < k3[s, d, m] <= 5, 
data[m] = Append[data[m], {s, d}]], {s, -1, 1, 0.01}, {d, -1, 1, 0.01}], {m, mm}]

ListPlot[data[#] & /@ mm, PlotStyle -> col]
```

[image]

**Rectifying the method in question**

```
ps = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 1, 0.05}, {j, 0, 1, 0.05}], 1];

styleps[m_] := Select[ps, (0 < k1[#[[1]], #[[2]], m] <= 10 &&
-2 < k2[#[[1]], #[[2]]] <= 2 && 0 < k3[#[[1]], #[[2]], m] <= 10) &];

ListPlot[{styleps[-3.5], styleps[-1.5]}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Sumit . Can not we in `ListPlot` define a range for `m` -> {-2,2} instead of discrete values ?

Comment: As you see, each `m` will give you one set. Best you can do is define it in a range with small interval, like `Range[-2,2,0.1]`

Comment: So how to probably define m in Range in your code ? .. I tried some things but it was going wrong for me

Comment: But just in my code can not we instead setting m = -3 , put m in `styleps` and then loop or take range on its values?

Comment: In your code what you are doing is writing the coordinates in blue or white ;) - so it is good as nothing. If you like to use your style, then I would suggest use `Select`. It will reduce your data size as well and then use with `ListPlot`.